# iOS 9 App links not working as intended with URL Shorterning

Tags: ios, applinks

I followed iOS9 app links guide ([here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9)) and app links are working fine

i.e. Whenever i access http://www.domain-name.com/some_page it redirects to my application and handles it properly.

But if i shorten the exactly same URL then it launches Safari and fails to launch the application. am i missing some configuration?

Comment: This is likely because only the short url is scraped, and that does not contain the necessary app link tags.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you cannot use URL shorteners or the the URL will no longer be recognized by iOS as a Universal Link. We at Branch (who wrote the blog you reference) have seen this a number of times in troubleshooting with our partners.

If you use an email provider that automatically shortens URLs, you'll need to disable this if you want links to work as Universal Links.

Comment: in some cases URL shortening cannot be prevented. Such was when tweeting the URL (Twitter will always shorten the URL with its t.co service). This automatically makes all branch links broken, when posted on Twitter. Is there any workaround around this?

Comment: we fallback to URIs in some cases when we can safely fire them. That includes iOS Chrome. I suggest writing in to integrations@branch.io to debug this individual link. It may be that turning on Deepviews (another Branch product) just for Twitter is a partial resolution to this issue.